# Why do gods put bear foot on earth if they wear gold ornaments?

Tags: gods

If gods wear gold ornaments, then they will be defintely wearing some kind of golden shoes.

But in places where its mentioned that God landed on earth first time, we see foot marks only and not any shoe marks.

Do gods really wear ornaments if they appear as humans on earth? If they wont wear ornaments, I really doubt they wear cloths also then how come some devotees claimed that they have seen gods who have cloths?

Or else they are not real footprints of gods?

Today I have seen the foot of Lord Laxmi Narasimha Swami of Ahobilam in an Youtube video where they mentioned that those are foot prints of Laxmi Narasimha Swami.